# Error associated with Ajax Calendar Extender

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox to display date.Onclicking on textbox ajaxcalendar has to be displayed infront of textbox .But now its coming behind textbox.So not able to select date.Can anybody help to bring calendar infront of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to look into the "z-index" style attribute for both controls.
The one with the higher z-index value is closer to the viewer.